# Calling function causes TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, self

I'm trying to create a Python program that is able to open a youtube video, and then skip the ad in it. Here is what I have:

```
class MusicPlayer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        self.driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suia_i5dEZc")
        sleep(7)
        skipAd = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-ad-skip-button-container')

        def skipAdFunction(self):
            threading.Timer(3,skipAdFunction).start()
            if(skipAd.is_enabled() or skipAd.is_displayed()):
                skipAd.click()
        skipAdFunction()
```

However, I'm not sure why this is happening, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aivoices.py", line 52, in <module>
    MusicPlayer()
  File "aivoices.py", line 17, in __init__
    skipAdFunction()
TypeError: skipAdFunction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

It has something to do with `self`, but I'm sure if I'm supposed to have it or not. Can someone also explain me whether I need it in this occasion or not?

Comment: Is it intentional to define `skipAdFunction` within `__init__`?

Comment: Note that it's bad practice for `__init__` to have side effects that aren't directly related to data structure initialization. Work like starting a browser or waiting for an event should not be triggered by an initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead write `self.skipAdFunction()` when you call the function.

Alternatively, you can define `skipAdFunction` outside of the class and you won't have to mention `self` anywhere.

**Edit:**

As per Charles' comment, this is incorrect, my apologies. When you have a nested function defined within a class method, python does not expect/require you to have the positional argument self. Therefore, you can fix it like so:

```
class MusicPlayer():
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff you had here
        def skipAdFunction():
            threading.Timer(3,skipAdFunction).start()
            if(skipAd.is_enabled() or skipAd.is_displayed()):
                skipAd.click()
        skipAdFunction()
```

Comment: `self.skipAdFunction()` will work only if they take the function's definition out of the body of the `__init__` method; it needs to be directly under the class, not inside a method under the class, to be a method itself.

Comment: Hey! This error is fixed, but the function to click the add doesn't @mckennab

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're absolutely right. I'll edit my answer. Hopefully this fixes your bug as well Nicolas.

Comment: What's the point of defining that function at all? Where it is, it can't ever be called except from the `__init__` location where it already is involved already. I suspect that the OP _meant_ to be defining a method, not a function, so it could be called additional times on an already-existing instance later.

Comment: That's a fair point, although personally if I'm calling the same code multiple times in say a list comprehension, nested functions are pretty convenient. OP if you want to be able to call this function outside of `__init__`, you'll need to either add `skipAd` to your object (`self.skipAd = skipAd` in `__init__`) or pass it in as an argument to `skipAdFunction`.